# I need to finish a project written on VS 2008 and using AutoCAD What and how to reference AutoCAD libraries

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, autocad

I need to Finish a project written a couple of years ago on windows form vb.net on  VS2008. I pass the project to VS2010. I have AutoCAD 2013 on my computer. What is the Wright way to add the references for AutoCAD and where are they ? 
I basically need to read data from a table from an autocad drawing grammatically using vb

On the reference for the VS2008 project I can see some references such as

1. ACCTRLLib
2. Autodesk
3. AutoCAD.Interop
4. Autodesk.AutoCAD.Interop.Common
5. AxACCTRLLib

And when calling the namespace I see some like :

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Math
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Threading.Thread
Imports Autodesk.AutoCAD.Interop
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Server
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Imports Autodesk.AutoCAD.Interop.Common
```

I read some of the AutoCAD manuals as the one link below but it didn't help much. On this manual they also mention something between the .NET API and the Interop of AutoCAD.

[AutoCAD .NET Developer's Guide](http://docs.autodesk.com/ACD/2010/ENU/AutoCAD%20.NET%20Developer's%20Guide/index.html?url=WS1a9193826455f5ff2566ffd511ff6f8c7ca-4875.htm)

Please Any Help with these .. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you needing help trying to reference the namespaces you need or help reading data from a table, there's a difference. Also referencing `AutoCAD` is the same no matter the version. If you look at your 2008 project and expand references, you will find the path they are pointing to. If you installed a newer version you would need to hunt down the path's for them.

Comment: I need both. By looking at the code it looks like he has code to read a table from the drawing. I brought this code from an external hard drive so it does not shows me the path for the libraries so basically It gives me an error because it cannot find the libraries. So i want to make sure Im referencing the wright libraries. And where are they ?

Comment: `Where are they` I don't know as I can't tell you where they were installed at? They could be anywhere. Can't you search for them and see if you can located them?

Comment: Ok I will try that. Thanks for taking the time to answering my question.

Answer (score 2):

On the newer versions of AutoCAD, the Interop libraries are at the acad.exe folder, look for

Autodesk.AutoCAD.Interop.dll

Autodesk.AutoCAD.Interop.Common.dll

Comment: Probably you will need AcDbg.dll and AcDbmgd.dll with "Copy Local" set to false. And be ware of the "Copy Local" property of the other references.

Comment: and accoremgd.dll is required on 2013+, but from your original question, looks like a pure COM Interop app, you only need AcDbMgd, AcDbMgd and AcCoreMgd if you are developing a app that will run in-process (NETLOAD on AutoCAD)

Comment: @AugustoGoncalves sorry for the question I'm new on this. What do you mean by the app that will run in-process (NETLOAD on AUtoCAD). And thanks for taking the time to gave your feedback on this quesiton

Comment: on AutoCAD, you can call the NETLOAD command to load a .NET DLL. If that's your case, then you can use the Ac***Mgd DLLs. Now if you plan to use an external app (.exe) that will invoke AutoCAD, then you can only use Autodesk.AutoCAD.Interop DLLs